# Java comparing Objects with one parameter

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters, compare

I am self studying java and can't quite understand this problem. Let's say I have two Objects, and want to compare them in a method. 
How do I do that without changing the amount of parameters in method?

I can't seem to get the parameter of the other animal into the method, as it only takes on parameter. Does it have something to do with comparables?

```
public class Animal {
  private double size;
  private double length;

  public Animal(double size, double length) {
    this.size = size;
    this.length = length;
  }

  public compareSize(Animal animal) {
    //if (dog.size <  animal.size)
      //return 0;
    //return 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal cat = new Animal(100.0,30.1);
    Animal dog = new Animal(200.0, 09.5);
    System.out.println(dog.compareSize(cat));
  }
}
```

Comment: try: `this.size < animal.size`.

Answer (score 2):

You define the method `compareSize` in the class `Animal`.

In Java (and in all other OOP languages) when you call a method on an object, this object is accessible with the `this` keyword.

When you call `dog.compareSize(cat)`, you are calling  `compareSize` on your `dog` object, so in your method `this` will be referencing the `dog` object.

Thus you need to compare `this.size` and `animal.size`.

The [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface has nothing to do with this.
The Comparable interface allows your class to be comparable, by defining the `compareTo` method. It is required to use useful methods like [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

Also, you need to define the return type in your `compareSize` method, its signature should be :
    public int compareSize(Animal animal)

Comment: Oh I see. The lack of return type in the method was a typo, but I had some confusion about the .this reference. Now I feel like I 'got it'. Thank you very much, this felt really important!
Thanks to all other answers as well!

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the method as follows:

```
public int compareSize(Animal animal){
if (this.size < animal.size){
    return -1;
}else if(this.size > animal.size){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

What is happening here is that when you use "this" it is referencing the size in the object where the method is being invoked.
i.e if you are doing dog.compareSize(cat), you are invoking compareSize in the dog object.
hence this.size inside dog object will return 200.0

if you did cat.compareSize(dog), this.size would return 100.0

How you would use this is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Animal cat = new Animal(100.0,30.1);
    Animal dog = new Animal(200.0, 09.5);
    System.out.println(dog.compareSize(cat)); 
}
```

Though in terms of coding standard using a comparator would be better, you can learn in more details about comparators here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable but you will have to pass two parameters into the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareSize()` method could simply be:

```
public int compareSize(Animal animal){
    return Double.compare(this.size, animal.size);
}
```